# Opening PDF from a web page in android stock browser

Tags: android, pdf, web, download

The web application that I am developing has a link to generate a document in pdf format. On clicking the link the server-side code generates the PDF and streams it back to the browser with content type set as "application/pdf".  This is working as expected in all the browsers except the android stock/default browser. On clicking the link in the stock browser, the pdf download starts in background. The user has to go to the notification area to actually open then pdf.

Is there a way to make the browser directly open the pdf instead of doing the background process?

Answer (score 1):

here's ur answer:
just append ur URL with google url and send it to browser;

```
 case R.id.btnSchoolMenuView:
            Log.d(TAG, "Lunch Btn "+lunchMenuUrl);
            String googleUrl = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";
            Log.d(TAG, googleUrl + lunchMenuUrl);
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(googleUrl + lunchMenuUrl));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
            break;
```

Comment: I am developing only the server side code not doing any development on android. But, I get your trick - you are using google docs to show the page. Unfortunately, i cannot go for this solution since there are some legal/security restrictions that prevent me from using third party websites to show the report. Thanks, though! I was looking for a solution on the server-side involving some fancy content-disposition header for the stock browser or maybe some javascript trick on the browser.

Comment: One more update. This solution does not work if the user is already logged into their google account. Gdocs looks for the document in the user's library in such cases.